# Google Play Service вообще никак не работает на устройстве!

Tags: c#, unity3d

Разрабатываю игру, дошло до интеграции сервисов гугла, все сделал по туториалам, имеется функция, которая выполняет sign in:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
public Text t;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}
public void click(){
    t.text = "click!!!";
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration c = new 
PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder ().Build ();
    t.text = "click1";
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    t.text = "click2";

    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance (c);
    t.text = "click3";

    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
    t.text = "click4";

    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool suc)=>{
        t.text = "click5";

        if(suc) t.text = "Yes!";
        else t.text = "No!";
    });
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Дефолтная надпись в тексте - `"Text"`. Так вот, если я запускаю приложение в самой Unity и нажимаю на кнопку, то мне, конечно же, отчетливо пишет `"No!"`, но если я запускаю приложение уже на устройстве, то при нажатии текст вообще никак не меняется и соответственно никакой авторизации нет... - это и есть проблема, в `play console` связал приложение, проверил SHA-1, мыло тестировщика записано. Еще раз отмечу, смущает именно то, что на устройстве мне даже `No!` не пишет.

Использовал `Unity Remote`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На телефоне пишет только "Click"...
Выяснил, что доходит до Click4 на устройстве

Comment: Вы debug логи то покажите. У вас на устройства метод `click` то вообще вызывается? Добавьте туда лог в самое начало.

Comment: Вот вся необходимая информация

Comment: Выше указаны скрины работы в самой unity

Comment: Выяснил, что доходит до click4

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема и не в авторизации, и не в Google Play:

1. Проверь, срабатывает ли вообще метод click, потому что на телефонах и планшетах нету мышки :)
2. Найден ли вообще компонент text? Если он нулевой тогда и понятно, почему нету даже надписи "No".

Если и это не помогло, тогда можешь просто расставить Debug.Log через строчку, и тогда ты с точностью отследишь, до куда код вообще работает.

Comment: Эти вещи я знаю, они сделаны сразу по привычке), дело не в них

Comment: Показал скрины выше, видно и текст и то, что срабатывает метод

Comment: Выяснил, что доходит до click4 (смотрите код)